# How to couple these random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am doing this exercise:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p_1,...,p_n$ and $X=\sum X_i$.

> a) If $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent what is $P[X_1=...=X_n=0]$

**My answer**: $P[X_1=...=X_n=0]=P(X_1=0)\times...\times P(X_n=0)=\prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)$.

> b) Under what conditions on the $p_i's$ can you couple $X_1,...,X_n$
>   in such a way that $P(X_1=...=X_n0) \geq 1/2$

**My answer**: Suppose $p_1=p_2=...=p_n$ with $p_1<1/2$ then let $X_i:=X_1$ for $i=2,3,...,n$. Then $P(X_1=...=X_n=0)=P(X_1=0)=1-p_1 \geq 1/2$.

> c) Couple $X_1,...,X_n$ in a way that maximises $P(X_1=X_2)$ and give
>   this maximum probability in terms of the $p_i's$.

**My answer:** No idea how to do this.

> d) Suppose $p_i=1/n$ for all $i$. Calculate $E(X)$. What is the
>   largest and smallest possible values for $Var(X)$ (Over all possible
>   couplings of $X_1,...,X_n$).

**My answer**:

$E(X)=E(X_1)+...+E(X_n)=nE(X_1)=1$. Then I'm stuck.

Would anybody be able to tell me if I'm correct on part b) and show me how I should answer parts c) and d) please.

I am really stuck on these.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

c) $P(X_1=X_2=0) =1-P(X_1=1)-P(X_1=0,X_2=1)\le 1-p_1$, and similarly $P(X_1=X_2=0)\le 1-p_2$. Therefore $P(X_1=X_2=0)\le\min(1-p_1,1-p_2)$. For a coupling that attains this bound, let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and define $X_k=1_{[0,p_k]}(U)$ for $k=1,2$. This idea extends to consideration of more than 2 of the $X_k$s, and can be used to improve your answer to part b).

d) When the $X_i$s are iid, the variance of $X$ is $1-1/n$. When the $X_i$s are completely coupled as in your answer to b), the variance of $X$ is $n-1$. The maximal variance is $n-1$, as you see by using Cauchy-Schwarz. The minimal variance is $0$. This can be attained  by taking $X_k=1_{[(k-1)/n,k/n)}(U)$, where $U$ is as before. In this case $X=1$ almost surely.